# Efficient and Scalable Way to Handle Time Series Analysis with Large Datasets in Python

Tags: python, pandas, performance, time-series, data-analysis

I'm working with a very large dataset (over 100 million rows) of time-series data in Python. Each row represents a separate event with a timestamp, and there are multiple events for each timestamp. I need to perform analysis on this data, such as aggregating events by time intervals (e.g., by minute, by hour), calculating moving averages, etc.

Here's a simplified example of what my data looks like:

```
import pandas as pd

# Example data
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'timestamp': pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', periods=100000000, freq='S'),
    'event': ['event{}'.format(i % 100) for i in range(100000000)]
})
```

The standard **pandas** approach for time-series analysis (e.g., using **resample** or **rolling**) is too slow for this amount of data.

I'm aware of Dask as a potential solution for handling large datasets, but I'm not sure if it's the best tool for time-series data, and if so, how to use it effectively for this purpose.

So, my question is: What are some efficient and scalable ways to handle time-series analysis with large datasets in Python? Are there specific techniques, libraries, or paradigms that are well-suited to this kind of problem?

I'd appreciate any advice or examples that could point me in the right direction.

I attempted to use the built-in pandas function **resample** to aggregate my data by minute. Given the size of my dataset, I expected this operation to be time-consuming, but hoped it would complete in a reasonable timeframe.

However, the operation took far longer than expected, and I had to terminate it before it completed. As a result, I was unable to perform the required analysis on my data.

I also tried using the **rolling** function to calculate moving averages, but faced similar performance issues. The computation was not only slow, but it also consumed a large amount of memory, causing my system to slow down significantly.

Therefore, I'm looking for a more efficient method to handle time-series analysis on large datasets in Python. My objective is to find a solution that can perform these operations faster and with less memory usage.

Comment: this is statistics as opposed to computational: But, i would start with a statistical sample of the data. this would immediately reduce your cost significantly...

Comment: say you produce a simple moving average for a 30 day rolling window. This would equate to ~ 3 billion calculations.  So the answers will be interesting !

Comment: Pandas is not efficient for large dataframe. AFAIK, no Python high-level library is actually efficient. Some are faster than Python because they use more resources (threads or machines) but this does not make them more efficient (actually, possibly less per execution unit). Nearly all Python library have the same issue: they do not case about the CPU cache and travel the dataframe many times. This is a big issue because of the ["memory wall"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory#Memory_wall). This issue is getting worst over time and it is not planned to be fixed any time soon.

Comment: *CPUs are very fast, but DRAMs are slow*. This gap is even bigger on computing servers. The key to better use caches is to extract chunks of the dataframe and do the maximum amount of operation you can on it. Computing a mean M1, then M2, then M2 (for different groups) can be 3x slower than computing M1, M2 and M3 at the same time travelling the dataframe once. Low-level languages help you to do that easily, not much for Python. You can use Cython and Numba to do this quite efficiently though as long as the operations are quite basic (moving averages are basic).

Answer (score 1):

For working with large datasets, I would recommend you working with `PySpark`.  [`Apache Spark`](https://spark.apache.org/) (whose `python` interface is [`PySpark`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/#)) is a distributed data processing engine which optimises processing of large datasets both on clusters and single machines. Here is an interesting [article](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2018/05/03/benchmarking-apache-spark-on-a-single-node-machine.html) which compares the performance of `pandas` and `PySpark` on a single machine and how `PySpark` performs better.

Also, if you ever want to move to a cluster for your computations (which might become necessary given the amount of data you have), writing your code in `PySpark` would allow you to make a seamless transition.

**Edit: Primary Reason why I personally recommended `pyspark` and not `DuckDB` or `Polars`**

Recommendations are always personal and depend on the preferences and criteria one considers most important - some people might recommend `DuckDB` or `Polars` over `pyspark` and, if they have valid reasons which make sense in their context, that seems perfectly fine to me. We know very little about the context of OP apart from the fact that OP uses a lot of data, which is why I won't elaborate on aspects such as "solution integration", "ability to leverage solution in the cloud", "ability to distribute work amongst team members", etc.

The primary reason for me to recommend `PySpark` is **Community Size:** When choosing between various approaches where all provide the functionality that is needed, I personally would always go for the one which has the biggest open-source community; *generally* the larger the community, the more features and the more support (also on StackOverflow) you'll get. In my opinion the picture below shows compellingly whose community is the largest.

[image]

Comment: what about duckdb, or polars? Any reason to choose pyspark over those?

Comment: Hi @baxx! Thanks for your question :) I've edited my answer and provided a reason why I recommend `PySpark` over `DuckDB` and `Polars` - hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Matt, I guess you missed the part where I literally wrote "Recommendations are always personal and depend on the preferences and criteria one considers most important". If you have a different opinion, feel free to share your recommendations.