# Effective Approaches for Optimizing Performance with Large Datasets in Python?

Tags: python, django, performance, bigdata

I am currently working on a project that involves processing large datasets in Python. While I have managed to make it work, I am facing performance and efficiency challenges, especially when dealing with massive amounts of data.

To provide more context, let's assume I have a dataset with millions of records, and I need to perform complex computations or data transformations on it. Currently, my code takes a significant amount of time to process the data, and it seems to consume a considerable amount of memory, leading to potential memory errors or slowdowns.

Here's a simplified example of my code structure:

```
import pandas as pd

def process_large_dataset():
    # Load the large dataset into a DataFrame
    df = pd.read_csv('large_dataset.csv')

    # Perform computationally intensive operations
    # ... (complex computations or data transformations)

    # Store the processed data to a new file or database
    df.to_csv('processed_data.csv', index=False)
```

I would like to optimize my code and improve its efficiency when handling large datasets. Specifically, I am seeking advice on the following areas:

Memory Management: What are the best practices for reducing memory usage when working with large datasets? Are there any techniques to minimize the memory footprint during data loading, processing, or storage?

Speeding up Processing: How can I accelerate the data processing tasks to improve overall performance? Are there any optimized functions or algorithms available that can handle large datasets more efficiently?

Avoiding Bottlenecks: What are the common bottlenecks or performance limitations when working with large datasets in Python? Are there any specific areas of my code that could be potential bottlenecks, and how can I address them?

I am open to leveraging popular libraries like pandas, NumPy, Dask, or any other relevant tools. Additionally, I am willing to explore alternative code structures, parallel processing techniques, or any other strategies that can significantly enhance the performance and efficiency of handling large datasets in Python.

I would greatly appreciate any advice, suggestions, code examples, or references to relevant resources that can help me overcome these challenges and optimize my code for efficient large-scale data processing.

Thank you so much for your valuable assistance!

Comment: You don't say exactly what sorts of computations/transformations you're doing, but the solution to your problem is probably going to involve a database *of some kind* so that you can eliminate the bottleneck of having to load a single CSV into memory all at once.  The devil is in the details -- depending on what exactly you're doing with your data, some databases might be able to do those transformations themselves, or maybe the role of the database is simply going to be facilitating parallelization.

Comment: These are very broad questions and the only thing we know about your data is that it's stored as .csv (which is an interesting choice for a truly large dataset) and that it's "large". Your questions all have generic answers that can be looked up in any serious source of knowledge about data management - what exactly is the problem you're having? If you're hoping for an answer along the lines of "use framework X with algorithm Y", prepare for disappointment. As with any question on a subject like this, the answer is "it depends, it's complicated."

Comment: As for "bottlenecks with [your] code" - you shared two lines that actually do something. The bottleneck there is clearly that you put all your data in a single file of a text-based format that needs to be parsed (i.e. .csv)...

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, to choose a good approach to tackle your problem, you should ask yourself the following: **"Do I need all of my data in memory to perform my computations?"**

**If the answer is no,** you can stick with `pandas` and perform your computations in chunks, leveraging `chunking`. Below, I pasted a simple example of how you can do `chunking` with pandas and add a column to a dataset while only loading 1/10th of the data into memory at a time. There's also a `pandas` user guid on [scaling](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/scale.html). You could also look into [`polars`](https://www.pola.rs/) which was specifically designed to handle datasets much larger than your available RAM.

**If the answer is yes,** you should look into performing your calculations on something such as a `spark cluster`, which is a framework that has been specifically designed for large-scale, parallel data processing. Another SO user also sought help regarding a good approach to process millions of observations, where I recommended [`PySpark`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/#) in his case - you can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76249575/8718701)

Example of how to perform `chunking` in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create dummy data with 1 million rows
data = {
    'col_1': [1, 2, 3, 4] * 250_000,
    'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] * 250_000 
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.shape)  # (1000000, 2)

# save to disk
df.to_csv('my_csv.csv', index=False)
del df

# load 100'000 rows at a time, process them, and save them
for i, df in enumerate(pd.read_csv('my_csv.csv', chunksize=100_000)):
    
    # perform your calculations for individual parts of your dataframe
    df['col_3'] = df['col_1'] + 1

    if i == 0:
        df.to_csv('my_new_csv.csv', index=False)
    else:
        df.to_csv('my_new_csv.csv', index=False, mode='a', header=False)
del df    

# load entire dataframe to get shape
df = pd.read_csv('my_new_csv.csv')
print(df.shape)  # (1000000, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, when I'm choosing Python as my tool I tend to ignore optimizations like memory management and optimizing the current CPU. We certainly need to [look at the O of the code we're writing.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) However, if we want to dive further than that we should probably be choosing a different language.

That being said, I tend to choose Python because when I'm working on large data sets I'm doing it over a network tied to solutions better designed for the type of data problem. Typically Python is simply binding to different big data technologies.

So, instead of looking at the RAM of my instance, perhaps I look at my data in how it sits in a datastore like [Redis](https://redis.io/).

Then we ask questions like, can we use more than one thread or more than one machine? If the answer is yes, as it usually is, can we split up the larger dataset into parts and parallel process the parts. It honestly sounds a lot more complicated than it ends up being with Python, because there are many community task queue based solutions [such as Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/index.html)

So if we split our dataset up and queue up tasks for it, a scalable amount of workers can be put behind it to parallel process on a common set of memory, which might be a datastore or [even a NoSQL database such as MongoDB.](https://www.mongodb.com/)

If we find ourselves in the situation that we can't split up the data and we have to do that thing in one thread, we probably shouldn't be writing this thing in Python in the first place. I love Python. I use it for a ton of my work. But in these situations we should definitely be using a compiled language like C to actually get that race car performance. Python isn't the performant language. Large Python based systems are actually getting that performance from either making network calls [or being bound to C](https://realpython.com/python-bindings-overview/).

Answer (score 0):

@maxtymosh, thank you very much for your question! I have exactly the same one and can confirm that we are lacking resources on this topic. It has been a nightmare for me to work with large datasets and I have no idea how to handle them with the least amount of pain.

I have discovered something that can partially answer your question. My primary reason for posting it is to support a discussion on the topic you brought up.

First, the direct partial answer to your inquiry on how to speed up things. The ONLY way to speed them up is to use Numpy arrays. In other words, store your dataset in Pandas (in my case, it is Xarray). Use built-in simple functions for simple calculations (like .mean() or .add() etc.). Convert your dataset to a Numpy array to perform custom and not simple operations (like mapping a custom function). Parallelizing (with Dask in my case) doesn't help much (maybe for really huge datasets only). I also heard Cython helps, but I have not tried it and I do not know if and how it works with Pandas and Xarray.

Second, my experience.

I divide work with big datasets into 3 problem areas: loading, computation, and speed.

The first two are memory-related.

I have addressed the third one.

@SimonDavid addressed the first one. Simon David's answer matches what I have found out and I think that's the only way to work with big datasets: loading them in chunks. Simon David's answer is of extreme importance because he shows how to do it. The only thing I would add is that - from what I have found out - `del` operation does not necessarily free the memory and we can, still, overload the memory. Python does not allow users to manipulate the memory. The question of what to do in this case is still open for me (i.e. what is the best practice and if it is, in fact, to use `del` then I would like to hear the explanations on how exactly to use it in view that it does not necessarily free the memory).

That brings us to the last issue: computation. What I have encountered is the following. I was doing computations on my dataset using Numpy for speed. In a loop, I would create a Numpy array, do my calculations, and repeat the procedure. I was sure the Numpy array was reused at every iteration. But it was not. I kept filling up the memory. And it took only two iterations to fill up the memory. All those `del` things would not help me to free the memory after every iteration. That is what I mean by the memory problem during computation: what are the best practices to perform computations on a big data set and not to overload the memory?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a vectorized (multi-threaded) language such as IDL (Interactive Data Language) that was developed many years ago for just such a task. It also includes graphics for presentation and analysis. There is a freeware version called GNU.